# JavaScript Validation - page still being processed

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have a form:

```
<form name="char-add" id="char-add" action="added.php" method="post"
 onsubmit="charAddValidate()">
    <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" onkeyup="charNameSelected()" autocomplete="off" />
</form>
```

`charNameSelected()` simply shows the next div when something is typed into the box.

Then some Javascript code that acts on the form:

```
function charAddValidate() {
    x = document.forms["char-add"]["Name"].value;
    if (x == "" || x == null) {
        alert("Name is required");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The code works, if the name is left blank it does indeed give the alert box, but if I ok this, it continues to submitting the form anyway, resulting in my php validation error ;)

Where am I going wrong (I want it not to submit the page when js validation fails).  I know i'm probably missing something obvious to someone else :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try adding **return**:

```
… onsubmit="return charAddValidate()">
```

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your onsubmit to

```
"return charAddValidate();"
```